# How can I take a bunch of two-dimensional arrays of the same size and turn them into three dimensions?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

In `python3.7`, I have many two-dimension arrays of numpy which have the same size`(2, 2)` for example, [[1,2],[3,4]] and [[5,6],[7,8]].

How could I turn them into three dimensions as the  size of `(n,2,2)`,like [ [[1,2],[3,4]],   [5,6], [7,8]] ]. `n` is the number of arrays

Note: do not change it into the list, since the number of arrays is too much and it will out of my CPU's memory.

Comment: take a look at `np.stack`

Comment: presumably you already have a list of these arrays.  `np.stack(array_list)` works nicely, though `np.array(array_list)` is just as good.  Assuming that all the arrays have the same size.